# Trip to India from Abu Dhabi for an UAE residence

Tags: visas, india, greek-citizens

I am living and working at Abu Dhabi and I want to have a tourist trip to India. My passport is from Greece and is valid until 2020. How long will take to obtain a tourist visa ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a visa for India, but can apply for an electronic entry Permit [here](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/tvoa.html) (called "e-Tourist visa"), which has to be applied for at least 4 days before travel.

You present the E-Mail confirmation you get, as well your passport, at Indian border control.